# How To Make An If Statement Case Insensitive In Python

Tags: python, if-statement, case-insensitive

It can become quite tedious to put multiple variations of spelling into and if statement and I was wondering if there is a way I could make the if statements case insensitive so I only need to put in one thing. I'm just picking up python again and couldn't find a good way online.

Comment: Convert to upper or lower then compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [2]: s = 'aBcDe'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: if s.lower() == 'abcde': 
   ...:     print("look! it's case insensitive") 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
look! it's case insensitive
```